# Would using an extension method to query an IEnumerable be equivalent to using IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

I understand the main difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable. IQueryable executes the query in the database and returns the filtered results while IEnumerable brings the full result set into memory and executes the filtering query there.

I don't think using an extension method to query on the initial assignment of a variable will cause it to be executed in the database like IQueryable, but I just wanted to make sure.

This code will cause the full result set of People to be returned from the database, and then the filtering is done in memory:

(The People property on the context is of type DbSet)

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = context.People;
Person person = people.Where(x => x.FirstName == "John");
```

Even though I am adding the filtering below as an extension method before assigning the item to my variable, I'm assuming this code should work the same way as the code above, and bring back the full result set into memory before filtering it, right?

```
Person person = context.People.Where(x => x.FirstName == "John");
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies guys. I modified the code example to show what I meant (removed the IEnumerable in the second paragraph of code).

Also, to clarify, context.People is of type DbSet, which implements both IQueryable and IEnumerable. So I 'm not actually sure which .Where method is being called. IntelliSense tells me it is the IQueryable version, but can this be trusted? Is this always the case when working directly with a DbSet of a context?

Comment: Well what's the type of `context.People`? I suspect it's `IQueryable<Person>`, in which case no, they're not the same - your first code will call `Enumerable.Where`, and your second code will call `Queryable.Where`.

Comment: Assuming that `context.People` is an `IQueryable` and not an `IEnumerable` then the second option is faster as your database will be returning less data. When applying a `Where` to a queryable you still have a queryable

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.  It's the implementation of IQueryable, and the code that uses it, that determines its behavior.  The interface simply defines the shape of types that support linq-like operations against different providers.

Comment: The cause for the difference is that you assign `people` to an `IEnumerable<Person>`. Try using `var` or `IQueryable<Person>` and the results will be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = context.People;
Person person = people.Where(x => x.FirstName == "John");
```

... will execute the [IEnumerable<T>.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) method extension, which accepts a `Func<TSource, bool> predicate` parameter, forcing the filtering to happen in memory.

In contrast...

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = context.People.Where(x => x.FirstName == "John");
```

...will execute the [IQueryable<T>.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) method extension, which accepts a `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate` parameter. Notice that this is an expression, not a delegate, which allows it to translate the `where` condition to a database condition.

So it really does make a difference which extension method you invoke.

Answer (score 1):

IQueryable<T> works on expressions. It is effectively a query-builder, accumulating information about a query without doing anything... until the moment you need a value from it, when:

- a query is generated from the accumulated Expression, in the target language (e.g. SQL)
- the query is executed, usually on the database,
- results are converted back to a C# object.

IEnumerable<T> extensions works on pre-compiled functions. When you need a value from it:

- C# code in those functions is executed.

It is easy to confuse the two, because:

- both have extension functions with similar names,
- the lambda syntax is the same for Expressions and Functions - so you cannot tell them apart,
- the use of "var" to declare variables removes the datatype (often the only clue as to which interface is being used).

  ```
  IQueryable<int> a;
  IEnumerable<int> b;

  int x1 = a.FirstOrDefault(i => i > 10);    // Expression passed in
  int x2 = b.FirstOrDefault(i => i > 10);    // Function passed in
  ```

Extension methods with the same name *usually* do the same thing (because they were written that way) but sometimes they don't.

So the answer is: No, they are not equivalent.